# How to read and write session in helper--Cakephp

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, session, cakephp

I have to use the session in cakephp helper.

To read the session is possible in helper but write session is not.

I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone tell me?

Basic problem is that:

I have created one custom helper which call several times in view for single request.

Suppose helper has called for 5 times.

In helper for textarea some random id has going to be assign.

I need to collect those ids in some variable and then use it for the js function.

If you have new idea related to this problem then please share.

I have added the "session helper" in my custom helper.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend SessionHelper , for that place a create a ExtendSessionHelper.php in View/Helper

and add following code in it.

```
App::uses('SessionHelper', 'View/Helper');
class ExtendSessionHelper extends SessionHelper {
    public function write($name, $value = null) {
        return CakeSession::write($name, $value);
    }
}
```

Use following code in helpers array of controller to use this helper

```
var $helpers = array( 'Session' => array('className' => 'ExtendSession'));
```